# SQL Server: custom column sort in WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort the results of this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.my_field_name IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3');
```

...so that I get the results sorted in the same order as the IN list values.

In mySQL this can be done easily:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE my_field_name IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') 
ORDER BY FIELD(my_field_name, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3');
```

...but I don't know how to do it in SQL Server. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a case statement like this:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE field
      WHEN 'val1' THEN 1
      WHEN 'val2' THEN 2
      WHEN 'val3' THEN 3
   END, my_field_name
```

Comment: I accept this answer as the 'Accepted' one, because it's working fine, and it's easiest to apply in a high-complexity query with many joins and other fancy things. Anyway, Charlieface answer is also valid.

Comment: Beautiful answer! :-)

What if you have a LOT of values to specify in "CASE field"? Can you build that list dynamically instead of hard-coding each value?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to join on a `VALUES` virtual table, along with an ordinal to sort by:

```sql
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM t1 
JOIN (VALUES
    ('val1', 1),
    ('val2', 2),
    ('val3', 3)
) v(value, ord) ON t1.my_field_name = v.value
ORDER BY
  v.ord;
```

In the event that there are duplicate `value`s (eg if you were passing in parameters) you would need to aggregate them first.

Comment: Even though this answer works perfectly, I accept Bashton answer as the 'Accepted' one. Because it's easiest to apply in a high-complexity query with many joins and other fancy things dynamically generated. Thanks anyway. Answer is great.